# s3Client for amazon web services on android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am exploring using Amazon Web Services for storing user images to be viewed via my android aplication.

Problem is Amazon will charge me $0.12 per gig of downloads of that image. This cost could be minimal if i enable caching of those image urls but the s3 url generator for those file urls requires an experation date to be part of the url.  This means i wouldn't be able to cache those requests.

Is there a way to set up s3client to generate a URL that doesn't require an expiration data?

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. no thanks to amazon's own documentatio which is scattered and out of date..

you can set the permission to public read like so:

```
PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(
                        Constants.getPictureBucket(), Constants.PICTURE_NAME,
                        resolver.openInputStream(selectedImage),metadata);
                por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
```

then you end up getting a normal url:

> [https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[NameOfThePicture]](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/%5bbucket%5d/%5bNameOfThePicture%5d)